# The search in Ubuntu Software Center disappears

Tags: software-center

[image: img]

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit in vmware 9. The menu **Edit > Search** doesn't work. I tried to run in terminal `software-center`, but only get a lot of failure messages. I didn't resize the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Ubuntu Software Center from a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) using the command line:

```
software-center
```

If still doesn't work, you should resize the window of Ubuntu Software Center and make it a little bigger. If i resize my window to that size, the Search disappears because there's no space to it be shown.

Comment: Please read my post under the image. I tried but only got a lot of failure message. The image is here: http://i40.tinypic.com/33w8dqr.png

Comment: If i resize my window to that size, the Search disappears because there's no space to it be shown. So, maximize it!

Comment: It comes out. Thank you. If I design it, I will not layout the interface in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But this is crappy SW design on part of Ubuntu. When a window is re-sized, all controls should re-size themselves.